How to change numbers received from text file to integer
I used python script to read numbers form *.txt file and use that number for future works, but the number when I parse I am getting error "TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'list'"
BUt when I hard code number its working
with open(r'''C:\\MentorUTTFVC\ChangeSet.txt''') as f:
    for line in f:
        inner_list = [int(elt.strip()) for elt in line.split(',')]
        list_of_lists.append(inner_list)


length = len(list_of_lists)
for i in range(length):
   ch = int(list_of_lists[i])

ChangeSet.txt
30000
30002
30004
30008


Your list_of_lists is, well, a list of lists, so when you call list_of_lists[i], it will be a list, which is an invalid type to pass into the int function.

Why are you still using Python 2.7? It was EOL'ed several years ago.

Your file doesn't have any commas. Why are you using line.split(',')?

Also can you clarify what you are trying to accomplish with the ch variable?

You should have given the entire error trace.  I presume it's happening in ch = int(list_of_lists[i])?

@MarkRansom It seems almost definitely that an error is occurring there; a list is being passed into the int function.

Your file is not a CSV, you don't need to split it on commas. There's just one number per line, so you don't have to create a list of lists.
with open(r'''C:\\MentorUTTFVC\ChangeSet.txt''') as f:
    list_of_ints = list(map(int, f))

for ch in list_of_ints:
    print ch


Thansk Boss, I am very new to python. You saved my time
